# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_1_input to have shape (32,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

`model.fit` throws an error `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_1_input to have shape (32,) but got array with shape (1,)`, but there are no arrays of shape `(1,)` passed to `model.fit`.

```py
def create_model(vocabulary_size, input_word_count, embedding_dims=50):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(vocabulary_size, embedding_dims, input_length=input_word_count))
    model.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D())
    model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
    model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
    return model


def main(epochs, batch_size):
    # Parse input data as a numpy array
    positive_words = ...
    negative_words = ...
    words = np.concatenate((positive_words, negative_words), axis=None)

    # Create labels
    labels = np.empty(words.size)
    for i in range(words.size):
        labels[i] = 1 if i < positive_words.size else 2

    # Split into train & test
    split_at = math.floor(words.size * 0.75)
    [words_train, words_test] = [words[split_at:], words[:split_at]]
    [labels_train, labels_test] = [labels[split_at:], labels[:split_at]]

    # Create model
    model = create_model(len(word_dict), batch_size)

    # Train model on first batch
    print(words_train.shape, labels_train.shape) # => (51565,) (51565,)
    model.fit(words_train[0:batch_size], labels_train[0:batch_size],
        batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose=2, #validation_data=(words_test, labels_test)
    )


main(200, batch_size=32)
```

I would expect the error message to indicate which value / parameter / layer / etc was the incorrect size. I am unsure what `embedding_1_input` refers to.

Comment: What is in x_batch and y_batch?

Comment: @Akaisteph7 both are arrays of shape `(32,)` containing floats

Comment: @Akaisteph7 specifically: `x_batch = [3.923e+03 7.360e+02 5.030e+02 2.530e+02 0.000e+00 9.300e+01 1.460e+02
 0.000e+00 8.000e+00 5.180e+02 8.549e+03 2.718e+03 4.560e+03 5.130e+02
 4.780e+02 6.400e+01 1.100e+01 4.956e+03 5.800e+01 4.764e+03 6.400e+01
 4.218e+03 6.380e+02 1.559e+03 8.000e+00 8.450e+02 5.150e+02 3.530e+02
 4.226e+03 1.450e+02 1.999e+03 3.660e+02]`, `y_batch = [2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2.
 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2.]`

Comment: any resolutions on that? I am having the same problem

Comment: Same problem. Any advice?

Comment: Same issue here as well