# reshaping vectors into tensors for embedding layer in keras LSTM mini-batch training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, word-embedding

I'm trying to train an LSTM topic model (many-to-one problem) on text using an embedding layer and mini-batch training in `keras` with `tensorflow` backend in Python. I am struggling with formatting my inputs and outputs in a way that is compatible with the embedding layer format.

My input consists of batches of [count-vectorized](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/applied-text-analysis/9781491963036/ch04.html) text tokens, post-padded to 50 cells. My output is a vector of iteger labels corresponding to one of 4 classes, likewise post-padded to 50 cells.

This is an example input vector:

```
array([2777, 2879,  114,  207, 2879, 3031, 1831,  565, 1961,  161, 1503,
       1485, 1036, 3380, 3255, 2879, 3243, 2152, 2406,  653, 3122, 3053,
        623, 1145, 2152, 3255, 2529, 3210,  119,  944,  161, 2879, 1282,
       2846,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0], dtype=int32)
```

And this is the corresponding output vector:

```
array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)
```

As a whole, my inputs and outputs consist of a list of padded arrays each. Next, I initialize my model architecture as follows:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding

model = Sequential() 
model.add(Embedding(20000, 100, input_length=50)) 
model.add(LSTM(100)) 
model.add(Dense(4, activation='sigmoid')) 
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

My [embedding layer](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/) has three parameters: (1) input dimension of 20000, corresponding to the size of my vocabulary, (2) output dimension of 100, which is the arbitrary dimension of the dense embedding, (3) inout length of 50, which is the maximum length of my post-padded vectors.

```
print(model.summary()) 

_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 50, 100)           2000000   
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 100)               80400     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 4)                 101       
=================================================================
Total params: 2,080,501
Trainable params: 2,080,501
Non-trainable params: 0
```

To simplify the batching problem, I train my model in a `for`-loop, passing one batch at a time. So my input is now correctly specified to be in 2D as required by the embedding layer (as per an earlier error stating `expected embedding_1_input to have 2 dimensions` after I tried to reshape to 3D.

```
for X, y in data:
    model.fit(X, y, epochs=1, batch_size=1, verbose=0)
```

When I try to fit the model, I get this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_1_input to have shape (50,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

This is really puzzling, because when I double-check the dimensions of my input they are indeed (50,)!

```
np.shape(data[0][0])
> (50,)
```

Transposing a 1 dimensional vector does not make any difference, so I'm not sure how to proceed at this point. Any advice?

I also noticed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56960432/valueerror-error-when-checking-input-expected-embedding-1-input-to-have-shape) post has a similar question, but so far no one has attempted to answer it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure what you are trying to do with that reshaping but `Embedding` layers expect 2D tensor, not a 3D tensor that you are trying to push through this layer.

Here is what documentation says about the input of `Embedding` layer

> 2D tensor with shape: (batch_size, sequence_length)

So you just pass it the 2D tensor with shape `(50, your sequence length)`

As for the `26300` number - it expects the length of a single batch, not a number of batches.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I undid the reshaping, so that my input is in 2D, but the emedding layer still won't accept my input, even though it is of the size it says it needs, which is quite puzzling. Do you know why that is the case?